# Efficient (non-crypto-grade?) pseudorandom permutations with arbitrary domain size

Tags: ds.algorithms, permutations, pseudorandom-generators

I'm looking for an efficient/simple (even if not necessarily cryptographically strong) algorithm for implementing pseudorandom permutations with domain cardinality other than a power of 2.  (FWIW, the domain cardinality I'm interested in at the moment is $900,000$.)

All the algorithms I've found for doing this aim for cryptographic strength, and tend to be relatively slow and intricate.

One exception to the last point, arguably, is the [standard Feistel network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_network) algorithm, which is at least fairly simple.  Unfortunately, AFAICT, this algorithm works only for permutations with domain size $2^{2m}$, with $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

(I've found some generalizations of Feistel networks to arbitrary domain sizes, but they all aim for cryptographic strength, at the expense of performance (and simplicity).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[unbalanced numeric Feistel](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/301.pdf#page=10) (page 10)

[swap-or-not](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/shuffle.pdf)

[FastPRP](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/254.pdf)

Those are all cryptographically strong; I'm not aware of

any way to get better performance by sacrificing that.